# Shutter speed and exposure time of picamera

Tags: picamera

Is it possible to control the exposure time and shutter speed of raspberry pi camera. If yes, how ?

Comment: are those two things not the same?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can control shutter speed and many other things.

For example

```
raspistill -ISO 800 -ss 6000000 -o out.jpeg
```

Will set the ISO 800 and the shutter speed to the maximum 6,000,000 microseconds, or 6 seconds.

[Here’s the Raspberry Pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md).

Answer (score 2):

You can control the shutter speed in python with the package [picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Installation for python 3:
`sudo apt-get install python3-picamera`

Documentation for the shutter speed method:
https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_camera.html#picamera.PiCamera.shutter_speed:

> shutter_speed
>
> Retrieves or sets the shutter speed of the camera in microseconds.

This example sets the shutter speed at 1000us, captures an image and saves it (all other parameters such as ISO, resolution... are set to default).

```
import picamera as picam

with picam.PiCamera() as mycam:
    mycam.shutter_speed = 1000 # 1ms
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.capture_sequence(['yourimage.jpg'],use_video_port=True)
```